# Zapier action to save file from API

Tags: javascript, zapier

I'm trying to create an action in zapier that will fetch raw bytes from my api and use it in zapier zaps after that.I actually stuck now, because none of what i've read in docs is working for me. Please any advice.

```
const options = {
  url: `my test api call`,
  method: 'GET',
  raw: true,
  headers: {
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${bundle.authData.access_token}`
  }
}

const stashPDFfunction = (z, bundle) => {
  // use standard auth to request the file
  const filePromise = z.request(bundle.inputData.options);
  // and swap it for a stashed URL
  return z.stashFile(filePromise);
};

var result = z.dehydrateFile(stashPDFfunction, {
  options: options
});
return result;
```

Comment: are you seeing an error message of any kind? what's the current output?

Comment: yep, I have smth like this: http://prntscr.com/pn0omj

Comment: The question is closed, I fixed the issue by using "dehydration" feature (https://platform.zapier.com/cli_tutorials/hydration). Let me know if you need help with this in pm.

Comment: @imressed the code snippet in your original post, is it a working version now?

Comment: Is the above code a working copy now?